# Run a string in python

Tags: python, eval

I get a string as an input, I want to execute it and then return the result (it should be safe).

eval can't execute lines like "x=7"
and exec doesn't return a value.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "return the result"?  Your example `x=7` doesn't have a _result_ in the usual sense.

Comment: You can provide dicts as local and global namespaces for exec. Check them for "x" after execution.

Comment: To compute a _value_ and then assign that to a known variable, you can use this: `x = ast.literal_eval("7 + 5")`.  However, as the function name implies, this can only work with literal values; you can't use other variables in the expression.

Comment: `exec` doesn't return a value because the definition of a variable doesn't return anything. However, it will map `x` into the global namespace, and `x` will be accessible to following `exec` statements. For instance, run `exec('x=7'); exec('print(x)')`

Comment: it cannot be safe.

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
exec("x=7; print(x)")
```